# Main loop in assembly for a Brainfuck interpreter

Tags: performance, assembly, interpreter, brainfuck, x86

I have written 2 Brainfuck interpreters, one in C++, then another in C++ with Assembly inner loop. My interpreter code can be found [here](https://github.com/ethan-tqa/bfasminterp/tree/019b5b35da6a769b8c007cbf75d1b671d4b480f8) (C++/ASM, requires MSVC and MASM) and [here](https://github.com/ethan-tqa/bfinterpreters/tree/ada196048ee075a344f954d9d1e6632b3f7fa150) (C++).

Both are benchmarked using the mandelbrot BF program, run 20 times. After trying for a while, I managed to make the Asm version about 10% faster than the C++ version, but I'm wondering if it can be made even faster. The main bottlenecks appears to be branch mispredictions and uOps cache. The benchmark ran on SkylakeX CPU.

The inner loop looks like this:

```
interpret proc C
.code
    push rbx        ; these are callee saved ?
    push rsi
    push rdi
    push rbp
    push r12
    push r13
    push r14
    push r15
    sub rsp, 32     ; shadow space?

    xor rsi, rsi    ; "program counter", which instruction we are at
    mov rdi, r8     ; "memory pointer", where we are pointing to in the interpreter memory
    xor r14, r14    ; store the value of current mem cell, which of course starts at 0

    lea r15, [jumptable]                ; load the address of the table
    mov r13, rcx    ; base address of instruction array

lbl_interp_loop:    ; beginning of new interpreter cycle
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

ALIGN 4
lbl_Loop:
    cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0
    jne lbl_set_loop_ip
    add rsi, r11

lbl_set_loop_ip:
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

ALIGN 4
lbl_Return:
    cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0
    jne lbl_set_return_ip
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

lbl_set_return_ip:
    sub rsi, r11
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

ALIGN 4
lbl_Right:
    add rdi, r11
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

ALIGN 4
lbl_Left:
    sub rdi, r11
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

ALIGN 4
lbl_Add:
    add byte ptr [rdi], r11b
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

ALIGN 4
lbl_Minus:
    sub byte ptr [rdi], r11b
    movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
    movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
    inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
    jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]

lbl_Print:
    movzx rcx, byte ptr [rdi]
    call printChar
    jmp lbl_interp_loop
lbl_Read:
    jmp lbl_interp_loop
lbl_Invalid:
    jmp lbl_interp_loop

jumptable:      ; MASM cannot emit relative address in .data, so must put it in .code this way (agner)
    dq lbl_Loop
    dq lbl_Return
    dq lbl_Right
    dq lbl_Left
    dq lbl_Add
    dq lbl_Minus
    dq lbl_Print
    dq lbl_Read
    dq lbl_Invalid
    dq lbl_End

lbl_End:
    add rsp, 32
    pop r15
    pop r14
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop rbp
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    pop rbx

    ret
interpret endp
end
```

Here is the report from V-Tune:

[image: V-Tune perf]

1. Before this inner loop begins, the interpreter does a couple of simple transformation on the BF source, turning it into instructions that consist of a 2 byte opcode and 2 byte operand. Repeated instructions are collapsed into 1 instructions and the number of repeats is stored in the operand. Loop/Repeat instructions contain the index of the destination instruction it jumps to.
2. Because of (1), there is no advantage of storing the value of current cell in register. In fact, when I tried to do that, performance got slightly worse. That is because when the interpreter encounters Left/Right instructions, it must save the current cell to memory and load the next cell, probably causing a data dependency on the register.
3. The reason why code for Loop and Return instructions are different, is because after changing code for Loop (`[` in BF) to have rare case right after `cmp`, I found performance increased considerably, but back fired for Return (`]` in BF) instruction. That seems counter intuitive to put rare case after `cmp`, but it seems to works here. V-Tune indicates a reduction in branch misprediction rate too.
4. Another strange example is right after label `lbl_set_return_ip:`, where I originally wrote:

   ```
   mov rax, r11
   sub rsi, rax
   ```

   but then found out that rewriting it as below noticably improved performance:

   ```
   sub rsi, r11
   ```

   Which is strange because I expected the `mov` to be pretty much free through register renaming.
5. The same data dependency problem leads to the fact that I relied on array indexing instead of increasing the pointer. This code

   ```
   movzx r10, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4]
   movzx r11, word ptr [r13 + rsi*4 + 2]
   inc rsi         ; advance to the next instruction
   ```

   is found to be faster than

   ```
   add rsi, 4 ; rsi contains the address of current instruction
   movzx r10, word ptr [rsi]
   movzx r11, word ptr [rsi + 2]
   ```

Comment: re: your comments with a `?`: yes, those are the call-preserved registers in the Windows x64 calling convention.  And yes, since you use `call` inside this function, it needs to reserve 32 bytes of shadow space.

Comment: You have a lot of branch mispredicts, which is hard to avoid for an intepreter loop.  See Darek Mihocka's [The Common CPU Interpreter Loop Revisited: the Nostradamus Distributor](http://www.emulators.com/docs/nx25_nostradamus.htm) article, which discusses this problem and presents some more branch-prediction-friendly techniques for writing an interpreter.  (For machine code in that case, but not much different for an interpreted language.)  See also [X86 prefetching optimizations: "computed goto" threaded code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46321531), but code-cache misses prob. won't happen for

Comment: You don't need to save/restore registers you aren't actually using.  For example, you leave RBX unused.  IDK if it would help any to save code size by avoiding REX prefixes by using 32-bit operand size and avoiding R8..R15  in some instructions.  e.g. `movzx ebx, word [rsi]`.  You could also look at doing pointer increments instead of array indexing.

Comment: Maybe cache the current valid of `[rdi]` in a register, like `bl`?  So instead of a memory-destination `add` or `sub`, you have a shorter dep chain: just `add ebx, r11d` / `mov [rdi], bl`.  (But it means you have to keep that cache in sync by updating it every time you change RDI.)  I don't know how often BF code changes the pointer without reading data vs. repeatedly modifying the same location.  Same-location repeatedly will create a loop-carried dependency chain which you can shorten by caching in a register.

Comment: Put rare cases out-of-line.  e.g. `cmp [rdi],0` / `jz rare_case`.  You want the common case to be not-taken, unless some other factor makes that worse.

Comment: Doesn't masm's `align 4` really mean align on the next 4 byte boundary (some asms use this to mean shift amounts)?  If so, Intel recommends aligning branch targets on 16 byte boundaries.  Might be worth a shot.

Comment: I agree with Ross.  I didn't feel like any of my comments amounted to a proper SO answer, but thinking back after posting them, I realized that they amount to part of a code-review answer.  The comments with `?` seem to be asking for a code review.  Definitely a better fit there since this is working code.  Flagging for migration.

Comment: BTW, you're not front-end bound other than branch-misses.  Your code is being fetched from the uop cache 99.7% of the time, which is unsurprising for such a tiny code footprint.  Using `align 32` might possibly help some.  (uop cache lines care about 32-byte boundaries, not 16.  Or possibly only 64-byte in Skylake?  32B alignment is probably sufficient.  See https://agner.org/optimize/)  A generic 16-byte alignment recommendation doesn't make much sense here, though, because you're always hitting in uop cache, not dealing with fetch-blocks.  Just avoid being near the end of a 32-byte block.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for commenting. I was expecting you haha. I have added an edit to the original question to address some of your points. The comments with question marks are mainly notes for myself to look at later though, not really for review.

Comment: MASM is not happy with ALIGN 32, gives me this error: error A2189: invalid combination with segment alignment : 32. Meanwhile, ALIGN 16 makes the interpreter run slower. Admittedly, ALIGN 4 makes no differences than not having it.

Comment: Don't forget to \@notify people when you reply.  If MASM doesn't support 32-byte alignment, use a better assembler (like NASM).  Unless that's a limitation of the object file format.  But maybe you need a directive somewhere to tell MASM that the whole code segment needs 64-byte alignment if you want to be able to specify alignments up to that.  In NASM, an `align` directive sets a lower bound on the alignment of the segment, so `align 4096` just works (on Linux making ELF binaries).

Comment: Interesting update.  Yeah, I can believe that special cases, especially when tuning for interpreting one specific BF program, will find quirks like branch prediction doing better with a taken branch.  TAGE predictors use the taken/not-taken history of the most recent N branches (regardless of address) as part of how they index a prediction entry for the current branch, so maybe taken there matches a pattern better.  [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342); It still costs a front-end uop, and space in the ROB.

Comment: Your pointer-increment sequence has the increment before the loads?  `movzx r10d, word ptr [rsi+4]` / `movzx r11d, word ptr [rsi+4 + 2]` / `add rsi, 4` puts the `add` after the loads, instead of before, so it's not adding to the load/use latency.  (And BTW, compiling to 2-byte opcode / operand bytecode sounds reasonable.  Loading with `movzx word ptr` is good.  Writing to a 64-bit dest register is redundant vs. letting implicit zero extension work, but it shouldn't matter.  Code-size probably doesn't really matter here, so avoiding REX prefixes normally won't help.

Comment: BTW, I think having an indirect `jmp` directly to the next block is basically what Darek's Nostradamus Distributor idea was.  Loading opcode+operand before jumping is great, because on a branch miss the load is done.  You might gain more performance by fusing two *different* operations into one in the parser.  So e.g. you could look for `add` / `left` pairs, and have a special opcode that does add *and* left without a `jmp` in between.  As well as separate `add` and `left` blocks.  Other common patterns are candidates; you have lots of coding space.  (Maybe consider 1B opcode / operand?)

Comment: If your "opcode" is actually a code offset directly, instead of a table index, you could do computed jumps instead of memory-indirect, maybe reducing branch-mispredict penalty by making the correct address ready a couple cycles earlier.  If you space each code block evenly, like `align 64`, then `add r10, r15` / `jmp r10`.  Or they don't even have to be spaced evenly if your opcodes just have the offset relative to r15 (which should point at the handler for the first one).  You could do `lea r10, [r15+r10*8]` with `align 8`.  (I might turn these comments into an answer tomorrow....)

Comment: I tried 1B opcode/operand but that didn't pan out well, as complex BF programs like mandelbrot usually exceed 255 instructions. I'm not sure if variable length complex instruction would help. The idea of code offset is interesting, but I need to find a way to obtain that offset value in C++ code, because that's where the instruction encoding happens. Or maybe rewrite the whole interpreter in pure ASM.

Comment: Masm does support larger alignment sizes, but you can't use a larger alignment size inside a function than you declare for the segment that contains it.  Try something like `_TEXT2 SEGMENT ALIGN(64) 'CODE'` instead of just `.code`

Comment: Can't you make the second argument only 16b signed value, so you can then collapse the right/left into single instruction? Also `add/minus` are by their nature single instruction, just adjust the byte operand for minus. The loop/return are then almost identical, just the test condition is different, hmm...

Comment: I would actually maybe try to encode instructions as 8:24, i.e. something like `mov eax,[...]` `movsx rcx,eax` `and eax,0xFF` `sar rcx,8` -> `rax` has 8 bit opcode, `rcx` has 24 bit sign-extended operand. This will allow for ~8mil instruction long tape/program, seems sufficient for toy interpreter with 8 bit data type.

Comment: @Ped7g: Not sure that's a good idea, but implementation-wise, `movsx rcx, [rsi]` / `movzx eax, cl` / `sar rcx,8` has no extra latency for the opcode, instead of 2c extra latency.  And a shorter dep chain for the operand, too.  This technique would work with the current 16:16, except that `movzx r10d, r11w` isn't zero-latency (only byte->dword movzx is zero latency.)

Comment: @Ethan: data-cache pressure is probably negligible, just use 16:16 if you need large operands for jump displacements.  Variable-length encoding would probably hurt.  To expose the offsets to C++, either use `global` on your code labels and declare them as `extern "C" extern const char my_label[]` in C++ and do pointer subtraction, or create a `global offsets` / `offsets: dw 0,  label1-base, label2-base, ...` array that the C++ can read as `extern "C" const short offsets[]`, indexed by whatever you're using now for opcodes.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I tried your method, and while it does compile, the end result is worse performance. The extra nops seems to add more pressure on the front end.

Answer (score 3):

I'd expect that most of the performance problem comes from the indirect branch (`jmp qword ptr [r15 + r10 * 8]`) - it's relatively unpredictable and should cause lots of branch mispredictions, bad speculations and pipeline stalls.

There's only really 2 ways to deal with this:

1) Amortise the cost. For example, if you packed 4 instructions into `r10` and had a significantly larger jump table you could reduce the number of indirect branches the CPU has to do to 25% (and therefore reduce the branch mispredictions, etc). Note that BF only really has 8 instructions so you only need 3-bit opcodes, so packing 4 together could cost 12 bits and give you a 4096-entry jump table.

2) Use JIT techniques. This would probably be an order of magnitude faster, but would involve a significant "redesign and rewrite". [ADDED] For one possibility, instead of pre-compiling the BF into a "16-bit opcode + 16-bit operand" form, you could precompile BF instructions into a series of `call ...` 80x86 instructions and then execute the resulting series of calls. This wouldn't be "full JIT" (wouldn't be generating native code for the actual work) but it would be using "JIT techniques" (to generate code to optimise the whole "fetch and decode" part of the interpreter).

Comment: WRT point 1, it sounds like some code generation would be required? I don't quite understand how to armotize it that way. OTOH I'm afraid that a 4096 entry jump table is quite large, and the generated code to accompany it would be way too large, missing L1i cache every 4 BF instructions. Finally, with 3 bits, I can encode 8 opcodes, but if I would like to have additional "meta" opcodes that encode multiple BF instructions, there will be no space left. WRT to point 2, I will consider JIT at a later time, but this experiment is about pushing the basic interpreter to its limit.

Comment: @Ethan: 1) is a much more aggressive version of my fusion suggestion from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031865/how-to-improve-the-inner-loop-performance-of-this-bf-interpreter#comment91015677_52031865).  And yeah, I'd be worried about uop-cache misses and BTB misses (more different branch targets = harder to predict).  L1i misses not so much.  But a given BF program wouldn't always use all of those 4096 entries in a hot loop, so not all of them would have to stay hot in the uop cache.  And yeah you'd probably want to macro it.

Comment: @Ethan: You would need to do some code generation; but you're already doing some code generation (e.g. converting to "2 byte opcode + 2 byte operand"). If you want you could think of it as a single 12-bit meta opcode (or a pair of 6-bit meta opcodes, or four separate 3-bit opcodes) - there's no practical difference.

Comment: @Ethan: Also note that when I said "JIT techniques" I didn't necessarily mean "full JIT only". For example, one of the JIT techniques that (I think) Bochs uses it to build a kind of trace cache, so that the whole "decode" part is skipped the second time instruction/s are executed. Mostly, there's a whole grey area between "pure interpreted" and "JIT" that consists of applying (some) JIT techniques. Note: this gives me a new idea (that I'll add to my answer).

Comment: IMO, it's not really JIT unless you write native machine code (for the host machine) into memory and execute it, requiring `mmap`/`mprotect` or `VirtualAlloc`/`VirtualProtect`.  Decoding into an easier-to-interpret format which you cache is great but not JIT.  Even building traces is still not JIT; it's something a JIT compiler might do.  I guess you can look at it as dynamic recompilation into new bytecode, but normally "JIT" without extra qualifications specifically means generating native machine code.

Comment: Yeah I'd draw the line in the sand in the same way as @PeterCordes. There's definitely a spectrum of techniques from totally vanilla interpretation to full-on JIT, but to me it crosses the JIT line when it _executes code that was written at runtime by the process_. I.e., exactly when it needs to use `mmap` or whatever to change the protections to W+X as mentioned. For example, executing a generated sequences of `call` instructions, one per instruction is JIT, but executing an existing sequence of unrolled `call` instructions with memory-source targets that you generated is not...

Comment: ... even though the execution pattern and and performance characteristics are likely to be very similar!